# how to find the the system regional time zone name by java script

Tags: java, asp.net, javascript, web-applications

Hi i have a typical requirement in my web application, i have to fill a dropdown box with all system timezones and set the selected time zone where from the client is browsing.

Only timezoneoffset is not enough to handle this suituation, since there are two reasons
1.the latest OS having more than one time zone with the same offset
2.If Day light save is enabled or disable(can be detected from Javascript) the offset will vary.

is ther any ways of handling this in Java script?

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to find out what you want to know. I also don't understand why it matters; the offset reported by `getTimezoneOffset` is the important thing anyway. For configuring a site preference, the timezone offset provides a good starting guess for a default selection from a choice list, and then the user can provide the information directly.

Comment: The main reason for this request is logged in users will be taking the reports from various regional areas from a centralized server. User must be aware of thier own time zone toselect the correct one before taking the report. if the user selects a wrong one then the report will be normalized to a different time zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: [Auto detect a time zone with JavaScript](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/).

Comment: I read that article, and tried they were using each time zone offset with either DST enabled or disabled. if we refer the timezones from our OS, there are more time zone names with same offset for example(GMT +2:00) i have 9 entries.how to determine among them one is my query.

Comment: It makes no difference to your report, because a time zone is a region on Earth, more or less bounded by lines of longitude, you have 9 entries that fall within the same line of longitude. what matters is daylight saving (that's why in the article you only find 2 entries for (GMT +2:00). Just combine the entries based on (SupportsDaylightSavingTime,BaseUtcOffset) so you have: (UTC+02:00 - DST:True) Amman,Athens, Bucharest, Istanbul, Beirut, Cairo,Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius,Jerusalem,Minsk,Windhoek. (UTC+02:00,DST:False) Harare, Pretoria

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: 
Use this open source JavaScript project: [jsTimezoneDetect](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect). It is based on the code that MK linked here, which is great, but not enough since different regions within the same timezone start their daylight savings at different times. Hemisphere also plays a factor.

**Long answer**: 
One example is the -07:00 UTC timezone which basically has three sub timezones.

- US Mountain Standard Time (no daylight saving... this is Arizona)
- US Mountain Time (with daylight savings)
- Mexico Mountain Time (with daylight savings)

Assuming that you know your user's UTC offset you will now have to check whether your timezone uses daylight savings. Create one January and one June date and check these two dates. If their UTC offsets differ, then you are in a timezone that uses daylight savings.

Say that you have determined that your user is -07:00 with daylight savings, that means either US Mountain Time (America/Denver) or Mexico Mountain Time (America/Chihuahua). How to tell them apart? Well, the date they start their daylight savings differ.

US daylight savings starts in 2011 starts 13 March, and in Mexico it 4th April. So start with Denver and check if 13 march is summer time, no? Ok, check if 4th April is summer time. Yes? Bingo.